# Make input fields look like table cells in bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-table

I have a table in bootstrap 3

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
           <td><input type="text" class="form-control" /></td>
           <td><input type="text" class="form-control" /></td>
           <td><input type="text" class="form-control" /></td>
           <td><input type="text" class="form-control" /></td>
           <td><input type="text" class="form-control" /></td>
           <td><input type="text" class="form-control" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Can I make the input fields look like normal cells? I want the input fields to fill out the entire cells (without no input margin nor table cell padding). Just like an Excel spreadsheet where I have many cells and can write in each of them.

Answer (score 17):

Yup. Do it this way:

```
input {display: block; padding: 0; margin: 0; border: 0; width: 100%;}
td {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsbin.com/biqomurafage/1

Answer (score 12):

You could also try using contentEditable tables like this: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LLgub6ku/)**

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>A</th>
            <th>B</th>
            <th>C</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>1</th>
            <td><span id="A1" contenteditable>#####</span></td>
            <td><span id="B1" contenteditable></span></td>
            <td><span id="C1" contenteditable></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>2</th>
            <td><span id="A2" contenteditable></span></td>
            <td><span id="B2" contenteditable></span></td>
            <td><span id="C2" contenteditable></span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

span {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

*note, the content editable spans are required for IE to handle the contentEditable attributes correctly. [*Reference*](http://caniuse.com/#feat=contenteditable)

Comment: Awesome answer! May I add that you might want to put `min-height: 100% ` for the span in order to be able to click when empty

Comment: Does this work if you intend to submit the table as a form?

Comment: @paul B - sure you can use the html table cells as input fields for a form. Just set the `id` and the `name` for each of the cell you want to submit and treat it according to your form need. That was my need too.